# Backbone.js: How to get model validation error from collection.create

Tags: backbone.js

Trying to add a model using collection.create. I added validation on the model and it works in that when I try to create the model nothing happens. However neither the success or error callback is triggered, the page just sits there. How do I get the actual error back? (validation just returns a string like "this is wrong")

I believe the issue is that the error callback only fires on server returned errors. How do you catch validation errors from here then though?

```
self.collection.create({
     //attributes
   }, {
   success: function (model, response) {
       //this doesn't run
   },
   error: function (model, response) {
       //this doesn't run either
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation

> Returns the new model. If client-side validation failed, the model will be unsaved, with validation errors

```
var model = self.collection.create({
     //attributes
   }, {
   success: function (model, response) {
       //this doesn't run
   },
   error: function (model, response) {
       //this doesn't run either
   }
});
```

Now you can handle the error in 2 ways:
1) `using events`

```
model.on('invalid',function(){
  // error handling here
});
```

2)  `using flag`

```
   if(model.validationError){
       // error handling here
        }
```